# Wallet not updating with balance and database error

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization

I'm fairly new to using bitcoins and have been having some trouble with my wallet. I bought bitcoins on coinbase and transferred them to my bitcoin core wallet. The transaction was confirmed with 616 confirmations, but it has been several days and the balance has not shown up in my wallet. At the time, the wallet was was synchronizing with the network for what must have been a total of 24+ hours and was less than half way there. Last night, before it was done synchronizing, I got a database error and now it's "Reindexing blocks on disk" and is 3 years behind. Are my bitcoins lost or will they be visible in my wallet once my wallet is done reindexing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should be there when you are done synchronizing. I would just wait for bitcoinqt to finish syncing if you are not in a rush.

As noted by this post you can do a workaround to access your coins now if needed:
[My client stopped synchronizing, how can I access my wallet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4920/my-client-stopped-synchronizing-how-can-i-access-my-wallet?rq=1)