# Transactions confirmed on Blockchain but nothing received to my Blockchain wallet

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, client, miner-configuration, unconfirmed-transactions

I need some info/help. I have sent some Bitcoins to my Blockchain wallet. They have all be confirmed and done with. But it has been 2 days now and nothing has shown on my wallet. 
This is the transaction on Blockchain,

https://blockchain.info/address/14kQfsxstFMjhL1RJAngoiEU13BaVUVjbS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wallet not updating with balance and database error](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41227/wallet-not-updating-with-balance-and-database-error)

Answer (score 0):

The final balance and total received sit at:

> Final Balance  $ 395.48

So I assume you haven't been able to access the coins yet. What wallet are you using? Is it possible that you have multiple addresses in your wallet and you need to manually find the privatekey/balance of 14kQfsxstFMjhL1RJAngoiEU13BaVUVjbS? Because from the Blockchain everything seems fine.