# How do you get a job in the Bitcoin/Blockchain industry?

Tags: blockchain, finance, job

I'm 18 and would like a job working in the Bitcoin/Blockchain industry but I wouldn't know where to start.  Economics degree?  Perhaps working for the fin-tech branch of a bank?

I'm interested to know about how people in this industry got there, what they think about it, and any advice.

Comment: you should start with math and physics

Comment: Look at the backgrounds of [the top Bitcoin core devs](https://bitcoin.org/en/development#bitcoin-core-contributors).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find a Bitcoin-related job?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4858/where-can-i-find-a-bitcoin-related-job)

Comment: I've voted against this duplicate, because the linked question asks about job opportunity, while the one here seems to ask about required skills.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the backgrounds of [the top Bitcoin core devs](https://bitcoin.org/en/development#bitcoin-core-contributors).

Here are the top 3:

- [Wladimir J. van der Laan](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Wladimir_Laan)
  University of Groningen
  Institute for Mathematics and Computing Science (IWI)
- [Pieter Wuille](https://www.linkedin.com/in/pieterwuille/)
  computer science degree at U. of Leuven
- [Gavin Andresen](https://www.linkedin.com/in/gavin-andresen-6987971/)
  Bachelor's degree in computer science from Princeton